# Python GUI - Linking one GUI in a class to another class

Tags: python, widget, tkinter

What I am trying to do is to link a GUI from one class in a separate file to another. 
My first class is a main menu which will display a few buttons that will link to another window.
The second class displays a different window, but the problem I am having at the moment is that I don't know how to link the button in the first class to call the second class.
Here's the code I have so far:

First file, the main menu:

```
from tkinter import *
import prac2_link


class main:
    def __init__(self,master):
        frame = Frame(master, width=80, height=50)
        frame.pack()
        self.hello = Label(frame, text="MAIN MENU").grid()
        self.cont = Button(frame,text="Menu option 1", command=prac2_link.main2).grid(row=1)



root = Tk()
application = main(root)
root.mainloop()
```

second file:

```
from tkinter import *

class main2:
    def __init__(self):
        frame1 = Frame(self, width=80, height=50)
        frame1.pack()
        self.hello = Label(frame1, text="hello, its another frame").grid(row=0,column=0)
```

Comment: First off, `self.hello = Label(frame, text="MAIN MENU").grid()` is probably not what you want. They have to be on separate lines, like such: `self.hello = Label(frame, text="MAIN MENU")`, and then do `self.hello.grid()`. `obj.grid()` returns None, so then `self.hello` is now None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a new window, you have to use a `Toplevel` widget. You can use it as a superclass for your `main2` class:

```
class main2(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.frame= Frame(self, width=80, height=50)
        self.label = Label(self.frame, text='this is another frame')
        self.frame.grid()
        self.label.grid()
```

Then you only have to create an instance in the event handler of the `Button` in the other class:

```
class main1:
    def __init__(self, master):
        # ...
        self.cont = Button(frame,text="Menu option 1", command=self.open_main2).grid(row=1)
    def open_main2(self):
        prac2_link.main2()
```

Comment: Thank you, I managed to figure it out, but this way makes a lot more sense (and a lot less code!). Much appreciated.